# Copy Active Directory User Account with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm building a script to create AD user account based from a CSV (nothing special so far ;o). One particular paramter I'd like to add is "copy from xxx" whereby the new account will be a copy from an existing account (just like the "copy account" option in the AD Console.

Can this be achieved? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems straightforward enough.  Make a column in the CSV called "CopyFromAccount" or something.

Then, during the `Import-CSV | Foreach` loop throw an if / else statement in.

```
If ($_.CopyFromAccount -ne $null) {
     ... insert code to copy AD account here ...
}
Else {
     ... insert code to use other parameters on this line to create the account ...
}
```

There are several available examples on the internet for copying users in PowerShell.  Here's an example using the Quest AD cmdlets:  http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/copy-ad-accounts-with-powershell/

To use the New-ADUser cmdlet from Microsoft instead of Quest, check out the instance parameter.  More information is available in Get-Help or at the following URL:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx

It "Specifies an instance of a user object to use as a template for a new user object."

And is used like so:

```
$userInstance = Get-ADUser -Identity "saraDavis"

New-ADUser -SAMAccountName "ellenAdams" -Instance $userInstance -DisplayName "EllenAdams"
```

Comment: I also found that. I was looking for a non-Quest method :) (I prefer to stick with the standard toolset, so I know it runs everywere). I'm looking for the "insert code to copy" :) I've been looking but didn't find an example that actually works (there doesn't seem to be a -copyFrom paramter or a Copy-AdUser cmdlet). I'm currently working around it (taking only selected values from the copyFrom account, not copying the wole account)

Comment: Revised answer to provide sample code on copying users with New-ADUser.

Comment: Hi again Chris
My bad: I didn'd read your first post (and the manual) good enough, I somehow missed the last part. The instance-parameter is exactly what I need. Thanks for helping!